# how to solve MYSQL ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck on this for quite some time now, how do I get to remove this error from my code?

```
Update( select * from Location natural join ConsumerLocation )
SET StreetNumber = 123,StreetName = 'Fake Street', StreetType = 'Fakeville',GoverningDistrict = 'Melbourne',PostalArea = 9999
WHERE UserName='kush';
```

then i added something like this to my code

```
Update( select * from Location natural join ConsumerLocation )t1
SET StreetNumber = 123,StreetName = 'Fake Street', StreetType = 'Fakeville',GoverningDistrict = 'Melbourne',PostalArea = 9999
WHERE UserName='kush';
```

now it shows error code 1288: the target table t1 of the UPDATE is not updatable.

Comment: update a real table not a derived one

Comment: You cannot update a table which is derived from the result of a query.we can only update tables which really exist in the database at their base table level.